# How to remove comments when building TypeScript into JavaScripts using rollup

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, rollup

I am using rollup to build my TypeScript sources. I want to **remove comments ONLY, without any minification**, in order to hot update code when debugging.

I have tried `rollup-plugin-terser`, it can remove comments but it will also minify my code somehow, I cannot **completely disable the minification**.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-cleanup ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this too with just `rollup-plugin-terser`. It bases on [terser](https://github.com/terser/terser) so more information it's actually available on its README, here is the part related to [minification](https://github.com/terser/terser#minify-options-structure). So in your case this part of `rollup.config.js` should looks like:

```
plugins: [
  terser({
// remove all comments
    format: {
      comments: false
    },
// prevent any compression
    compress: false
  }),
],
```

Keep in mind, that you can also enable part of configuration for production only. So having declared `production` const in your `rollup.config.js` you can do like that:

```
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

export default {
  plugins: [
    production && terser({
      // terser plugin config here
    }),
  ],
};
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: This seems no longer working? https://github.com/terser/terser/commit/675e9035

Comment: @diegocr As far as see this removed the `beautify` option only, but  you should be still able to get the comments removed. Nothing mentioned in the docs that this feature has been removed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, the thing is that i tried this approach and "compress:false" was not working for me (it does still compresses/mangles the code), which lead me to find about that "beatify" commit and related. So, looks like there may was something wrong on my side if this does still work for you all.

Comment: @diegocr You are welcome. Hard to say what it's in your case. I can't check it by myself now, but as documentation stands, it's still possible to use it. It didn't also work out of the box for me and I needed to play with it a bit, so I would say it might be something on your side.

Answer (score 11):

Like @jujubes answered in the comments, the [rollup-plugin-cleanup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-cleanup) will do the task. I want to expand a bit.

Three things:

- Add `ts` to extensions list, like `extensions: ["js", "ts"]` — otherwise sources won't be processed, even if transpiling step `typescript()` is before it — I originally came here investigating why `rollup-plugin-cleanup` won't work on TS files and it was just `ts` extension missing ‍♂️
- *code coverage* is important; on default settings, this plugin would remove `istanbul` statements like `/* istanbul ignore else */` so it's good to exclude them, `comments: "istanbul",`
- removing `console.log` is a separate challenge which is done with [@rollup/plugin-strip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-strip) and it goes in tandem to `rollup-plugin-cleanup`. In my case, depending is it a "dev" or "prod" Rollup build (controlled by a CLI flag `--dev`, as in `rollup -c --dev`), I remove `console.log` on `prod` builds only. But comments are removed on both *dev* and *prod* builds.

currently, I use:

```js
import cleanup from "rollup-plugin-cleanup";
...
{
  input: "src/main.ts",
  output: ...,
  external: ...,
  plugins: [
    ...
    cleanup({ comments: "istanbul", extensions: ["js", "ts"] }),
    ...
```

Here's an [example](https://github.com/codsen/codsen/blob/c5756ca749e0b244b3ee1acf7deb884027eaa52e/packages/detergent/rollup.config.js#L155) of `rollup-plugin-cleanup` being used my Rollup config, here's my Rollup config [generator](https://github.com/codsen/codsen/blob/main/packages/lect/src/rollupConfig.js) (in monorepos, Rollup configs are hard to maintain by hand so I generate them). If you decide to wire up `--dev` CLI flag, the gotcha is you have to remove the flag from the `commandLineArgs` before script ends, otherwise Rollup will throw, see [the original tip](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/2694#issuecomment-463915954) and [it in action](https://github.com/codsen/codsen/blob/c5756ca749e0b244b3ee1acf7deb884027eaa52e/packages/detergent/rollup.config.js#L265).